# PHP semaphore (in same browser)

Tags: php, semaphore

If I want prevent multiple execution of a code **in same browser**, why PHP semaphore not working in same browser or another browser tab?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sem.php

This code work **only in different browsers**, why not working in same browser, when i execute script simultaneously in same browser (php7.4-fpm + nginx)

```
$semaphore_key = 25;
$semaphore_max = 1;
$semaphore_permissions = 0666;
$semaphore_autorelease = 1;
$semaphore = sem_get($semaphore_key, $semaphore_max, $semaphore_permissions, $semaphore_autorelease);

if(sem_acquire($semaphore, true) === false) { 
    echo "error";
    exit();
}else{
    echo "ok\n";
}

sleep(30);
sem_release($semaphore);
```

Comment: I don’t have access to anything that can run semaphores right now, but since you tagged this also as double-submit-prevention, do you really need it? Depending on your scenarios, there might be better alternatives.

Comment: hi i am not looking for a solution to the problem i want to understand why php semaphore does not work in the same browser, when i execute script simultaneously in same browser

Comment: Same browser or different browser that should not affect semaphore

Comment: for example, same problem: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sem-acquire.php#125342

Comment: when i execute same script / URL simultaneously, semaphores did not work, but when i execute same script / URL simultaneously and one script with random data for example URL?_=monkeypox, it works like expected, problem is same URL in same browser, i dont understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why but it is caused by the Chrome browser cache, the response from the server does not contain any cache headers, when I disable browser cache, it works like expected